# Diagonalization in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find a matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2-5A+6I=0$ is diagonalisable??

I tried by considering $A$ a particular matrix and putting the values in the given equation but it gives nine equations in nine variables and those too very complex .. is there any other way ??

Comment: Try using a diagonal matrix.

Comment: An equation cannot be diagonalizable, a matrix can be diagonalizable. Possibly you mean "a diagonalizable matrix $ A $ such that $ A^2 - 5A + 6I = 0 $", in that case you can simply pick $ A $ to be an appropriate diagonal matrix.

Comment: Sure i try thanks 4 the suggestion

Comment: @Starfall The statement was " an matrix A over R$ A^2-5A+6I $digonalizable . "

Comment: That is not what you say in your post, please check again. Also, if you want that last matrix to be diagonalizable, you don't have to do a lot of work - pick $ A $ to be any diagonal matrix, and you are done.

Comment: Yea it works thank you for the help 

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix satisfies it's characteristic equation. Solve the matrix equation to find eigen values. Then find corresponding eigen vectors. Construct matrix P of eigen vectors. Now you can diagonalize any matrix A using P^-1AP.

Comment: (A-3)(A-2) ?? For eigen vectors we needA